# Bash console crashed and 6GB storage space got used up

Tags: bash

I'm using windows 10 and yesterday I installed bash.

I have had no prior coding experience and using bash was a bit of a nightmare for me. I just needed it to run a simple code to join 2 images into one image for a batch of 800 pairs of images.

I made a lot of mistakes in the code as I was using code found online.

In the process, some code would result in an ever increasing output file and I had to close the console using task manager just to end the process. System resources would go very high.

After I had ended the console a couple of times I realized over 6GB of disk space has been used up.

The problem is I can't find any way of clearing that space since I can't see what's using it. I've tried using disk cleanup but that didn't help.

How can I clear all that 6GB space that's used up by a bad code and prematurely ended bash console?

Comment: Could you post your code? Without it there's very little to go off of.

Comment: I'll try to remember:
``` for index in $(seq 1 2 2000)
do
montage -tile 0x -quality 100 -background none -geometry +0+0 $index.jpg
done
```

I was using imagemagick - hence the montage part

Comment: This looks like a user support question (how do I figure out what's using up disk space and clean it up?), not a programming problem.

Comment: So far I agree with @melpomene, but regardless could you please post your code in the question, with the code formatting (four spaces before each line)?

Comment: Another good general "find the directory containing the big files" routine is simply to change to the directory you ran the script in (assuming output would be there or below) and then `du -hc -d 1 ./` which will list the directory sizes for all subdirectories below the current directory.

Comment: Can you not see what was created with a simple `ls -al` of the directory in which you ran the imagemagick command. It looks like you attempted to create a montage of many files.

Comment: I deleted the folder where I had ran the code so there's nothing where I can run the above commands of ls -al

Comment: I used glary utilities to check where the space was being used up - found it in appdata - windows couldn't see it, even if I had checked the show hidden files option. So got rid of 6.28GB - all of it was imagemagick using glary. 

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

You can try to execute "history" in bash and work out where the file is from the command line history

alternatively run:

```
find / -size 6G -ctime 0
```

This will search the whole file system for files changed in the last 24 hours that used 16G of data. Increment ctime if you don't find the file in question.

Comment: Perhaps a `-size +10M` or `+100M` would broaden the search to find files greater than 10 or 100 megabytes. Without the `+/-` you are looking for a file that is rounded up to `6G`.

Comment: Tried it but got messages saying I don't have permissions to access any folder

Tried with the word sudo as well which asked for my password but no change

Comment: I used glary utilities to check where the space was being used up - found it in appdata - windows couldn't see it, even if I had checked the show hidden files option. So got rid of 6.28GB - all of it was imagemagick using glary. 

Thank you for your time